# Application context form a cycle for Setter Approach but not for @Autowired in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am just creating filter in Spring Boot. But it is conflicting when I am using setter approach but not facing when using @Autowired.

ProjectConfig Class

```
import com.emon.security.filters.CustomAuthenticationFilter;
import com.emon.security.providers.CustomAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
public class ProjectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter;
    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAt(customAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticationFilter Class

```
import com.emon.security.athentication.CustomAuthentication;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        CustomAuthentication customAuthentication = new CustomAuthentication(authorization, null);

        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(customAuthentication);

        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Is working fine..

Same code is implementing constructor based approach:

ProjectConfig Class

```
import com.emon.security.filters.CustomAuthenticationFilter;
import com.emon.security.providers.CustomAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
public class ProjectConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private final CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter;
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    public ProjectConfig(CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter, CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider) {
        this.customAuthenticationFilter = customAuthenticationFilter;
        this.customAuthenticationProvider = customAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterAt(customAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

CustomAuthenticationFilter Class

```
import com.emon.security.athentication.CustomAuthentication;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public CustomAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String authorization = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");

        CustomAuthentication customAuthentication = new CustomAuthentication(authorization, null);

        Authentication authenticate = authenticationManager.authenticate(customAuthentication);

        if (authenticate.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate);
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

But is creating this error:

```
┌─────┐
|  customAuthenticationFilter defined in file [/home/emon/Code/SecutiryDemo/ss-5/target/classes/com/emon/security/filters/CustomAuthenticationFilter.class]
↑     ↓
|  projectConfig defined in file [/home/emon/Code/SecutiryDemo/ss-5/target/classes/com/emon/config/ProjectConfig.class]
└─────┘
```

Actually when I am using @Autowired based injection then I am not facing circular exception but when I am using constructor based injection then I am facing this error.

Comment: What's how it works. What is your question?

Comment: I have updated the question.. 'Actually when I am using @Autowired based injection then I am not facing circular exception but when I am using constructor based injection then I am facing this error.'

Comment: Sure, that's how it works.It is okay.